# How to Create searchable drop down list in excel by java code

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula

I want to create drop down list which must be searchable as user type, all related value must be selected.

My Java Code for this is :-

```
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    // Create a blank sheet
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("testing");

    // This data needs to be written (Object[])
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    // String fileType = ImportItemFileType.Medicine.name();
    String fileName = fileType.getType();

    Object[] columnName = new Object[1];
    columnName[0] = "AutoSearch";
    data.put("1", columnName);


    // Iterate over data and write to sheet
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    int cellnum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
        Object[] objArr = data.get(key);

        for (Object obj : objArr) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);

            // System.out.println("cell num---------------------------------------------------"+
            // cellnum);
            if (obj instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
            else if (obj instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer) obj);
        }
    }

    // department drop down
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("unm");
    list.add("hcg");
    list.add("star");
    list.add("changa");
    list.add(0, "");
    String[] departmentArray = new String[list.size()];
    departmentArray = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    XSSFSheet hiddenDep = workbook.createSheet("hiddenDepartment");
    for (int i = 0, length = departmentArray.length; i < length; i++) {
        String name = departmentArray[i];
        System.out.println("name  "+name);
        XSSFRow row = hiddenDep.createRow(i);
        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(name);
    }

    DataValidation dataValidationDep = null;
    DataValidationConstraint constraintDep = null;
    DataValidationHelper validationHelperDep = null;
    validationHelperDep = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
    CellRangeAddressList addressListDep = new CellRangeAddressList(1, 10, 0, 0);
    constraintDep = validationHelperDep
            .createFormulaListConstraint("hiddenDepartment!$A$1:$A$"
                    + departmentArray.length);
    dataValidationDep = validationHelperDep.createValidation(constraintDep, addressListDep);
    dataValidationDep.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
    workbook.setSheetHidden(1, true);
    dataValidationDep.setShowErrorBox(true);
    sheet.addValidationData(dataValidationDep);

    for (int j1 = 0; j1 <= cellnum; j1++) {
        if(j1 == 0){
            sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 2000);
        }else{
            sheet.autoSizeColumn(j1);
        }
    }

    String filePath = "";
    try {
        filePath = MY_PATH +  fileName + ".xlsx";

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out
                .println("howtodoinjava_demo.xlsx written successfully on disk.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here I have created 'hiddenDepartment' as hidden sheet which will be used to show drop down, which will be applied on A1 cell to A10 cell.

Problem is when my drop down have more that 50 values, i want to make it searchable as user type, only it's respective data need to be shown.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrIx9.png)

You can see drop down here in img.